# Get data from remote REST API (read only)

Tags: 7, http-request

We use a remote service (not Drupal) to publish press releases and to show those releases in a remote newsroom.

This remote service offers an API so we should be able to fetch and show the newsroom on our Drupal site. To use the API a custom token must be present in the request header and the method used must be GET:

```
Notified-Custom-Token: [TOKEN]
```

This is what I have done so far in a custom module named notified_api. [custom token] is replaced by a unique token genererated for our newsroom and [id] is replaced by our newsroom ID:

```
function notified_api_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  // Fetch newsroom from Notified API with custom token
  $headers =  array('Authorization'=>'Notified-Custom-Token [token]', 'Content-Type'=>'application/json' );
  $url = "https://api.newsroom.notified.com/api/newsrooms/[id]";

  $options=array('headers'=>$headers, 'method'=>'GET');

  $result=drupal_http_request($url, $options);

  dpm($result);
}
```

Partial result from the dpm:

```
... (Object) stdClass
url (String, 53 characters ) https://api.newsroom.notified.com/api/newsrooms...
status (String, 5 characters ) Done.
code (Integer) 401
chunk_size (Integer) 32768
data (String, 0 characters )
request (String, 438 characters ) GET /api/newsrooms/345345 HTTP/1.0 Authorizatio...
GET /api/newsrooms/345345 HTTP/1.0
Authorization: Notified-Custom-Token 9832502938403876504329820348ewieitrje...
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: Drupal (+http://drupal.org/)
Connection: close
Host: api.newsroom.notified.com

options (Array, 20 elements)
headers (Array, 5 elements)
Authorization (String, 258 characters ) Notified-Custom-Token 9832502938403876504329820348ewieitrje...
Content-Type (String, 16 characters ) application/json
User-Agent (String, 28 characters ) Drupal (+http://drupal.org/)
Connection (String, 5 characters ) close
Host (String, 25 characters ) api.newsroom.notified.com
method (String, 3 characters ) GET
```

What I get is a 401 message: **unauthorized**. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else have the same problem. By replacing the name "Authorization" like this:

```
  $headers =  array('Notified-Custom-Token'=>'my-unique-token', 'Content-Type'=>'text/json' );
```

... it worked and I got a success response with code 200. My mistake was to believe that Authorization was a mandatory name in the name/value pair.